# Why can we use limit inferior to calculate the expected value of a stopped process?

Tags: martingales, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times, local-martingales

Consider ($\tau_n$) a diverging sequence of stopping times (e.g. $\inf\{t: X_t>n\}$). We can write the stopped local martingale $X_t^{\tau_n}$ = $X_{t\wedge \tau_n}$, which yields $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} X_t^{\tau_n} = X_t$

I was solving some exercises and saw some people using $E[X_t] = E[\underline{\lim}X_t^{\tau_n}]$, where $\underline{\lim}$ is the liminf.

This equality is not clear for me (the use of $\inf$), and any help on the intuition behind it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The whole thing is related to optimal stopping theorem. It's only true with some good properties of both the martingales and the stopping time. Most commonly used is that $P(t\leq \infty)=1$ ,  and $\{X_n\}$ is uniformly continuous in expectation.